# Error with resultCode in onActivityForResult after calling startActivityForResult

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I am enabling Bluetooth services through an `Intent` and calling `startActivityForResult()` method as follows:

```
public void enableBT(BluetoothAdapter adapter) {
        if (!adapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBTIntent, ENABLE_BT_INTENT);
        }
    }
```

In this code, `adapter` is `BluetoothAdapter` object. After this I call `onActivityResult()` as follows:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == ENABLE_BT_INTENT)
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                 button.setText("Done");
```

But after I enable the Bluetooth, the `button.setText("Done");` piece of code is not executed.

Where is the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: result code is an integer.   Attempting to setText(resultCode) is using that integer as a resource id to get a string.  Is that what you want to do?

Comment: If not you can use button.setText(Integer.toString(resultCodd));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`button.setText(resultCode);` gives an error because `resultCode` is an `int` so its looking for a `resource` with that `id`. See the two methods of [setText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29). You can use

```
button.setText(String.valueOf(resultCode));
```

If you want the `String` value of that `int` to be displayed. Otherwise please explain better what you want to happen.

Comment: If I compare resultCode with Activity.RESULT_OK, then the comparison should return true or false(as per the situation be), isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, but that isn't what you are doing.

Comment: My apologies for twisting the question. I have updated the question with correct problem.

Comment: I misread the question. I think you want `ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE` instead of `DISCOVERABLE`. [From the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE)"The resultCode will be the duration (in seconds) of discoverability..."