# App crashes when I try to set the TextView

Tags: java, android

I have this class I've named Scoreboard that looks like this:

```
public class Scoreboard {
private int mScore = 0;
private int mHighScore = 0;

public void addPoint() {
    mScore += 1;
}

public int getHighScore() {
    return mHighScore;
}

public void setHighScore(int highScore) {
    mHighScore = highScore;
}

public int getScore() {
    return mScore;
}

public void setScore(int score) {
    mScore = score;
}

}
```

And I have a piece of code in my acticity that manipulates this class everytime the user passes a ball through a rectangle's gap and changes the TextView accordingly to show the user the score:

```
//Keeps track of score
            if (rectWhite1.getTheRight() > Math.round(mBallPos.x) - 5 && rectWhite1.getTheRight() < Math.round(mBallPos.x) + 5) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mScoreboard.addPoint();
                        scoreTextView.setText(mScoreboard.getScore());

                    }
                });
                Log.d(TAG, "If statement has been run3333!!!");
            }

            if (rectWhite2.getTheRight() > Math.round(mBallPos.x) - 5 && rectWhite2.getTheRight() < Math.round(mBallPos.x) + 5) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mScoreboard.addPoint();
                        scoreTextView.setText(mScoreboard.getScore());
                    }
                });

                Log.d(TAG, "If statement has been run2222!!!");
            }

            if (rectWhite3.getTheRight() > Math.round(mBallPos.x) - 5 && rectWhite3.getTheRight() < Math.round(mBallPos.x) + 5) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mScoreboard.addPoint();
                        scoreTextView.setText(mScoreboard.getScore());
                    }
                });

                Log.d(TAG, "If statement has been run1111!!!");
            }
```

Everytime I run the app it crashes whenever I try to use any method pertaining to the Scoreboard class I made. When I try to add a point it crashes, when I try to get the current score it crashes, etc. So my question is how do I avoid this from happening and change the score dynamically?

Comment: I suppose that depends on the output of logcat when it crashes. But I would make sure that you have properly initialized `mScoreboard`

Comment: @codeMagic I haven't initialized mScoreboard......I have tried to set it to null but that doesn't work

Comment: Then that's your problem. You need something like `Scoreboard mScoreBoard = new Scoreboard();` otherwise you are trying to perform operations on a `null Object`

Comment: @codeMagic Ok I initialized mScoreboard like you said and my app still crashes...could it possibly be that I'm passing an integer to the setText method or could it be that I'm running on the UI thread?

Comment: Yes, that would certainly do it. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278820/error-with-resultcode-in-onactivityforresult-after-calling-startactivityforresul/18278883#18278883

Comment: @codeMagic Ok yes that was the problem, it was passing an integer into the setText method; now it works THANK YOU!!!

Comment: No problem. You also should read http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html to learn how to use the logcat. That will help you to solve many of your future problems